# Disable toggling of pagination on horizontal scroll in aggrid

Tags: html, angular, typescript, pagination, ag-grid

I have to load the next pages when we reach current page limit by vertical scrolling.
I have used aggrid paramter `(bodyScroll)="loadNextPages()"`.
But it is toggling pagination when i scroll horizontally as well when I use column filters.
How to prevent toggling pagination on Horizontal scroll and toggle only on vertical scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the event from `bodyScroll` event.
Something like

```
(bodyScroll)="loadNextPages($event)"  

function loadNextPages(evt){
 if(evt.direction === 'horizontal') return;
}
```

[image]

Link to docs: https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-miscellaneous